# ImageView position and size

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a ImageView defined in XML, which I later on inflate for use.

I want at one point to be the size 400,200 (width,height), at at another (500,300). 
Also I want to put it on specific place on the screen, something like setting x,y coordinates (or Rect(left, top, right, bottom) would be nice).

I understand for this I must 'play' with the LayoutParameters, but then I can't find any info how to specifically do it.
Can anyone put few lines example just to understand this....

Comment: Please specify the location in your code where you are making the call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the position of the imageview in your code dynamically you can only change the positions by setting their margins to move them left/right and up/down. The following receives the layout params of the imageviews so that you can change the views' margins.

```
ImageView image;
// Gets the layout params of the imageview
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams)image.getLayoutParams();
// Sets the margins of the imageview, making it move to a specific location on the screen
param.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put in specified point of parent you can specify `android:layout_marginLeft` and  `android:layout_marginTop` in px or dp. It not so clear, but working.
Programmly you can call [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) `View.layout(int,int,int,int)`, but I cant find same XML parameter.

Comment: Yes I need it programmatically .. I defined the ImageView with scaleType "fitXY" and then do iv.setMargins(100, 100, 0, 0) - expecting that it would go 100 pixels down, 100 pixels to left. It doesn't move from the top corner...

Comment: You can use `View.layout(int l, int t, int r, int b)` method. reffer to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)